# Переадресация в поисковиках

Tags: joomla, хостинг

Доброго времени суток! В общем проблема заключается в том, что в поисковых системах (Яндекс, Google и т.д) при переходе на мой сайт происходит переадресация на левый сайт. Ранее такого не наблюдалось. Я хочу узнать, почему произошла эта проблема и методы ее устранения.  Также хочу заметить, что если ввести адрес моего сайта в браузер (в верхнюю строку для сайтов), то адресация идет на МОЙ сайт.
Эта проблема возникает только в поисковых системах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну ктото вам модифицировал какойто файл, средствами php или javascript подхватывается юзерагент и дальше что-то вроде

```
if(useragent == Googlebot)
{
   redirect "на другой сайт";
}
```

Смотрите файлы index.php и прочее! Попробуйте зайти на сайт как Googlebot, отключить javascript и т.д. Короче что-то нужно делать!

Comment: то есть я должен искать в index название сайта или как

Comment: Целиком внедренную модификацию, и не обязательно в index!